# Do I include a spouse's Traditional IRA when converting my non-deductible Traditional IRA into a Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, roth-conversion

I have a Traditional IRA funded with non-deductible funds (in addition to a Roth IRA) and my spouse has a Traditional IRA funded 100% with deductible funds.  I'm interested in converting 100% of my TIRA into my Roth IRA (a.k.a. backdoor Roth IRA) and wondering:

**Do I need to include my spouse's TIRA in any pro-rata tax computation on the rollover or are my IRA actions unaffected by my spouse's IRA accounts?**

We file jointly and my spouse is not covered by any workplace 401(k) or such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **I** in IRA stands for *Individual*.  You can do a backdoor conversion
of all or part of your Traditional IRA to a Roth IRA all by yourself
regardless of whether your spouse converts her IRA or not, and the 
taxable part of the rollover is determined by what *your* Form 8606
says, not what is on her Form 8606.
But since you file a joint return with your
spouse, she will have the ineffable joy of being as liable as you for the income tax that is due on the conversion: on a joint tax return, both spouses
are jointly and severally liable for the tax due (no halfsies). If
one person does not pay, the other is liable for the *entire* amount.

Comment: I don't follow on your comment on her being liable for the tax due on conversion.  When I convert, I'm only taxed on the increase, not on the non-deductible part, right?  Are you just highlighting that the tax implications are joint even though it's an **individual** IRA conversion decision?

Comment: You are correct that you will be taxed only on the increase in value of your Traditional IRA over and above the sum of all your post-tax contributions. However, be aware that if you have Traditional IRAs with pretax contributions _in addition_ to the Traditional IRA with post-tax contributions (basis) that you are planning on rolling over to a Roth IRA, then you will be deemed to have rolled over only a part of the basis, and a much larger chunk of money (more than just the earnings in the IRA being rolled over) will be taxable income. And yes, on a joint return, the tax obligation is on both.

Comment: I have no Traditional IRAs with pre-tax contributions, only post-tax.  The only pre-tax IRA's are my spouses so it sounds like I can safely convert without needing to do any pro-rata calculations as a result of her pre-tax Traditional IRA.